# How can I get a single object from a particular folder in an Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How can I get a single object from a particular folder in Amazon S3 bucket?

By Using the Asp.Net C# language, I don't know how to retrieve a single object that are in a folder in bucket of Amazon S3 Service?

What I tried so far:

```
var putRequest1 = new PutObjectRequest { BucketName = bucketName, Key = 
"Employee/Word.pdf", FilePath = filePath, }; PutObjectResponse response1 = 
await client.PutObjectAsync(putRequest1); var putRequest2 = new 
PutObjectRequest { BucketName = bucketName, Key = "Employee/Tenses.txt", 
FilePath = filePath, }; PutObjectResponse response2 = await 
client.PutObjectAsync(putRequest2);
```

Comment: Can you share the things you have already tried?

Comment: var putRequest1 = new PutObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Key = "Employee/Word.pdf",
     FilePath = filePath,
                };
PutObjectResponse response1 = await client.PutObjectAsync(putRequest1);
var putRequest2 = new PutObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Key = "Employee/Tenses.txt",
                    FilePath = filePath,
                };
                PutObjectResponse response2 = await client.PutObjectAsync(putRequest2);

Comment: you should be using GetObjectRequest not Put......

Answer (score 0):

From AWS Documentation [Get an Object Using the AWS SDK for .NET](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingNetSDK.html).

```
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Amazon.DocSamples.S3
{
    class GetObjectTest
    {
        private const string bucketName = "*** bucket name ***";
        private const string keyName = "*** object key ***";
        // Specify your bucket region (an example region is shown).
        private static readonly RegionEndpoint bucketRegion = RegionEndpoint.USWest2;
        private static IAmazonS3 client;

        public static void Main()
        {
            client = new AmazonS3Client(bucketRegion);
            ReadObjectDataAsync().Wait();
        }

        static async Task ReadObjectDataAsync()
        {
            string responseBody = "";
            try
            {
                GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Key = keyName
                };
                using (GetObjectResponse response = await client.GetObjectAsync(request))
                using (Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    string title = response.Metadata["x-amz-meta-title"]; // Assume you have "title" as medata added to the object.
                    string contentType = response.Headers["Content-Type"];
                    Console.WriteLine("Object metadata, Title: {0}", title);
                    Console.WriteLine("Content type: {0}", contentType);

                    responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd(); // Now you process the response body.
                }
            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error encountered ***. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unknown encountered on server. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but the question is if two objects with same key are stored in different folders of a bucket then what happened ?

Comment: If it's different folders, it wouldn't have the same key because the folder name is part of the key. ex. file1 key: folder1/sameFile.txt 
file2 key: folder2/sameFile.txt. So even if you have the same file in two different folders, you would have two different keys.